# Embed a CDF file into an EPUB 3

Tags: epub, html, embedding, cdf

Can a Wolfram [Computable Document Format](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/) (`CDF`) file be embedded in an `EPUB 3` container? If not, is it possible to convert the `CDF` to `HTML5` and then embed it?

Answer (score 4):

In principle a CDF could be embedded in an EPUB3 file, but it would not bring you much. You would need a reader that knows how to extract it and play it and those are currently not available.

For viewing (playing?) a CDF you need [to download and install software](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/). This a problem for acceptance, a problem that Wolfram would have avoided if they could, e.g. by writing the viewer in JavaScript. Not reaching acceptable performance of a JavaScript based implementation of a CDF viewer is probably the most likely reason why this is not done, assuming there are no other technical difficulties.

In [this table](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/compare-cdf/how-cdf-compares.html) you see how CDF compares to HTML5 and JavaScript, so it seems only a subset of the CDF functionality could be achieved by conversion to HTML5.

Comment: In your opinion, can I embed into an EPUB3: 

- a short demonstrating video that show a CDF file "in action";

- a Javascript based implementation of a CDF file that will not include any element of the CDF file (I have to substitute all of them with free images available online).

I have to use the "Wolfram FreeCDF terms of use"?

Thank you in advance!